# Changing image in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am new to jquery and may be my question is very basic.
I am implementing an expandable panel in jQuery and above that i have an image of + which is when clicked the panel will expand. i want to change that image to - when the panel is expanded. 
So basically i want to change the + image to - once + is clicked.

Below is my code plz help.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $('#addImage').click(function () {
             $('#pBody').slideToggle('slow');
         });
     });

</script>
```

```
        <asp:Panel ID="pBody" runat="server">
            Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
            esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur
        </asp:Panel>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery should be like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $('#addImage').click(function () {
             $('#pBody').slideToggle('slow');
             $(this).toggleClass('show-minus');
         });
     });

</script>
```

And then in your CSS you'd have something like this:

```
#addImage {
             background: url(plus-icon.gif);
             height: 30px;
             width: 30px;
             cursor: pointer;
}
#addImage .show-minus {
             background: url(minus-icon.gif);
}
```

And of course you're HTML would look like this:

```
<div id="addImage"></div>
```

NOTE: If addImage is already an a tag, you don't need the cursor, height and width lines in the CSS. If you'd like to set the height/width then make sure to add a display:block line in there too.

Answer (score 0):

Put that image in a class.
You can use `addClass` or `removeClass` to change the class on click.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#addImage').click(function () {
    $('#pBody').slideToggle('slow');
    if($('#pBody').is(":visible")) {
        $(this).attr("href", "http://domain.com/minusimg.png");
    } else {
        $(this).attr("href", "http://domain.com/plusimg.png");
    }
});
```